# Combining Java and Python in Apache Beam pipeline

Tags: java, python, transform, pipeline, apache-beam

Is it possible to combine Java and Python transforms in Apache Beam?

Here is the use case (i.e. dream plan): the raw input data has very high rate, and so some initial aggregation is needed in a reasonably fast language (e.g. Java). The aggregated values are then given to a few transforms (implemented in Python) and then passed through a stack of machine learning models (implemented in Python) to produce some predictions, which will then be utilized again in some Java code.

Is it possible in Apache Beam?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible. You need an [`ExternalTransform`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.14.0/_modules/apache_beam/transforms/external.html) and an expansion service.

See [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/wordcount_xlang.py#L73) a test pipeline that does this:

```py
counts = (lines
          | 'split' >> (beam.ParDo(WordExtractingDoFn())
                        .with_output_types(bytes))
          | 'count' >> beam.ExternalTransform(
              'beam:transforms:xlang:count', None, EXPANSION_SERVICE_ADDR))
```

Here `beam:transforms:xlang:count` is a URN of a transform that should be known to the expansion service. This example uses a custom [expansion service](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/testing/expansion-service/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/expansion/TestExpansionService.java#L59) that expands that URN into a Java `PTransform`, you can build your own along the same lines.

You can see how this example is started [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/9678149872de2799ea1643f834f2bec88d346af8/sdks/python/test-suites/portable/py2/build.gradle#L94).

Comment: Hey, Anton, that looks really interesting. Do you know of any examples of a Java-based pipeline calling a Python PTransform (or DoFn)? I saw that both Apache and Google are working on multi-SDK support, but have no idea what state that work is in. Any insights into that?

Comment: @PeterLittig really good question, have you been able to find any examples?

Comment: This might be beneficial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aePbNx8CZw0.